# how to remove 'order' type attribute

Tags: magento

I want to write a script to delete an attribute which was created by an extension. This attribute is somehow more complicated than catalog/product attribute, as when created, it added a column in the database and can't be viewed via attribute manager.

At first, I looked at that extension install script and saw

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup('sales_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'i4bulksend', array('type' => 'int', 'default' => '0', 'grid' => true));
$installer->endSetup();
```

So, to remove the attribute, I tried:

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup('sales_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->removeAttribute('order', 'i4bulksend');
$installer->endSetup();
```

But no luck, the column 'i4bulksend' is still there